# Average data by month for a given latitude and longitude?

Tags: r

I have a table with the following headers and example data

```
Lat            Long           Date          Value.
30.497478    -87.880258      01/01/2016       10
30.497478    -87.880258      01/02/2016       15
30.497478    -87.880258      01/05/2016       20
33.284928    -85.803608      01/02/2016       10
33.284928    -85.803608      01/03/2016       15
33.284928    -85.803608      01/05/2016       20
```

I would like to average the value column on monthly basis for a particular location.

So example output would be

```
Lat              Long         Month      Avg Value
30.497478      -87.880258    January     15
```

Comment: How `Lat` and `Long` were calculated?

Comment: @Patrick You need to give more information. How did the numbers were calculated? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `lubridate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date), Month = month(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Lat, Long, Month) %>%
  summarise(`Avg Value` = mean(Value))
dt2
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Lat, Long [?]
       Lat      Long Month `Avg Value`
     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 30.49748 -87.88026     1          15
2 33.28493 -85.80361     1          15
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i get the following error msg. Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function". Please can you tell me what i am doing wrong. Thanks again

Comment: You probably apply mutate to a function, such as df. You need to apply mutate to your data frame.

Comment: Worked well. Can you tell me code if i want to add median and SD also.Thanks

Comment: @Patrick Put `Median_Value = median(Value)` and `SD_Value = sd(Value)` in the `summarise` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following, but it first modifies the data frame adding an extra column, `Month`, using package `zoo`.

```
library(zoo)

dat$Month <- as.yearmon(as.Date(dat$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))

aggregate(Value. ~ Lat + Long + Month, dat, mean)
#       Lat      Long    Month Value.
#1 30.49748 -87.88026 jan 2016     15
#2 33.28493 -85.80361 jan 2016     15
```

If you don't want to change the original data, make a copy `dat2 <- dat` and change the copy.

**DATA**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Lat = c(30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 33.284928, 
33.284928, 33.284928), Long = c(-87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, 
-85.803608, -85.803608, -85.803608), Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("01/01/2016", "01/02/2016", "01/03/2016", 
"01/05/2016"), class = "factor"), Value. = c(10L, 15L, 20L, 10L, 
15L, 20L)), .Names = c("Lat", "Long", "Date", "Value."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

**EDIT.**
If you want to compute several statistics, you can define a function that computes them and returns a **named vector** and call it in `aggregate`, like the following.

```
stat <- function(x){
    c(Mean = mean(x), Median = median(x), SD = sd(x))
}
agg <- aggregate(Value. ~ Lat + Long + Month, dat, stat)
agg <- cbind(agg[1:3], as.data.frame(agg[[4]]))
agg
#       Lat      Long    Month Mean Median SD
#1 30.49748 -87.88026 jan 2016   15     15  5
#2 33.28493 -85.80361 jan 2016   15     15  5
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using the code and i get the following error message. Error in as.Date(dat$Date, "%m/%d/%Y") : object 'dat' not found. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong. This is my first time with R.

Comment: `dat`is the name I gave your dataset example. You can recreate it by copying and pasting the last part of my answer into your `R`session and run that code,`dat <- structure(...)`. If your real data is named something else use that name, obviously. Just replace `dat` by whatever your data frame is named.

Comment: thanks Rui. It worked out perfect for me. I imported a dataset using read.csv and called it dat and then your code did the rest. I have one question, when i use write.csv i don't see the output just the previous step where it adds another column called month. How can i export this final result in csv? Thanks again so much.

Comment: @Patrick You will have to save the result of `agg <- aggregate(...)` and then `write.csv(agg, "path/to/your/filename.csv", row.names = FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks Rui, This worked out for me. Took few seconds where excel was taking forever. My dataset is like 424,271 lines and if there was one data point for each day then the new agg csv would have condensed to 13,910 lines appx. However, it condensed to 11,342 lines which makes me believe there could be some days with multiple values. Its such a huge data set that it would be tough to manually check if everything went right. Would you have any suggestions as to how i can establish the code worked correctly for the huge dataset?

Comment: also, would it be possible for me to create 12 csv's one for each month instead of having all months in one file? i appreciate all your help.

Comment: sorry, i have already asked you two more question and i am going to add one more. Just like we have a column for avg, can you tell me how i can add median and SD.? Thanks again.

Comment: worked great. Thanks. any suggestions on how i can separate into 12 different csv one for each month. and second is there a statistical method to validate the results are correct ?

Comment: @Patrick As for the 12 csv, that's a different question, post it. As for validate, I don't understand, means, medians and sds are not valid nor invalid, they are statistics. The statistical hypotheses tests don't validate them, they do something else depending on what you want or need to check. You really need to be more specific and, probably, also post a question asking about what you want to validate.

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much Rui. appreciate all of effort.

Comment: Rui, I did same operation in excel and my 400,000 lines daily data condensed to roughly 20,000 lines but in R i only have 11,000 lines. Is there a limitation as to how much data the zoo package or R in general can process?

Comment: @Patrick No, there isn't. The only limitations would be available memory and the maximum length of the vectors envolved. Both these limits are far from being reached by data with 400,000 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: Thanks Rui. I'll probably post another question to compare the two csv and see what is different.